# Rendering an HTML form based on a specification in a string

Tags: c#, html, unit-testing, vb.net, serialization

Here's a brief explanation of my method:

1. Provide a string and parse it to HTML code respecting a specific format.
2. The accepted format is:

   > For dropdown menu : Test DropDown~Select:Options1; Options2;Options3--- --- For Text area: Test Text area~TextArea:text to display**

I am inheriting this VB code from a legacy system we are using right now and trying to replace with a C# system. Though the naming convention is off, it is not how I declare my variables/methods (look at my C# unit testing code to have an idea).

How I can maintain the tests? We change the CSS classes a lot, which means I have to change the produced HTML, which means changing my tests. Is that ok?

```vb
Public Function BuildHtmlControlResponsive(sourceText As String, indexNum As Integer) As String
      Dim out As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
      'To store the text after the "~" 
      Dim textSelection As String
      Dim tildeLocation As Integer
      'To store the text of the control to parse (EX:Text Area, Input , Options menu ...)
      Dim controlOption As String = String.Empty

      'To store the name the text of the label
      Dim textLabel As String = String.Empty
      'To store the list of options (If applicable)
      Dim contentText As String = String.Empty
      tildeLocation = sourceText.IndexOf("~"c)
      If (tildeLocation > -1) Then
        'This gets the text that comes after the ~. Example Company~TextArea would return TextArea. 
        textSelection = sourceText.Substring((tildeLocation + 1), (sourceText.Length - (tildeLocation + 1)))
        textLabel = sourceText.Substring(0, sourceText.IndexOf("~"c))

        'See if the string has the : sign
        If (textSelection.IndexOf(":"c) > -1) Then
          'This gets the text that comes before the : Example Company:TextArea would return TextArea. 
          controlOption = textSelection.Substring(0, textSelection.IndexOf(":"c))
          'This gets the text that comes After the : Example Company:TextArea would return TextArea. 
          contentText = textSelection.Substring(textSelection.IndexOf(":"c) + 1)
        End If

      End If

      out.Append("<div class=""form-group"">")
      out.Append("<label for=""extField_" & indexNum & """ class=""col-md-4 control-label"" id=""extLabelField_" & indexNum & """ >" & textLabel & ":</label>" & vbCrLf)
      out.Append("<div class=""col-md-8"">")

      If (textSelection <> String.Empty) Then
        Select Case controlOption.ToUpper()

          Case "TEXTAREA", "TEXT AREA"
            out.Append("<textarea id=""extField_" & indexNum & """ class=""form-control"" type=""text"" rows=""3""  placeholder=""" & textLabel & """> </textarea> ")

          Case "SELECT"
            If (sourceText.IndexOf(";"c) <> -1) Then
              ' list box.  Syntax: name ; option 1 ; option 2 ; ...
              Dim OptionList As String()
              Dim i As Integer
              OptionList = contentText.Split(";"c)

              out.Append("<select class=""form-control""  id=""extField_" & indexNum & """>")
              For i = 0 To UBound(OptionList)
                out.Append("<option>" & OptionList(i) & "</option>")
              Next
              out.Append("</select>")
            Else
              ' text box. Syntax: name
              out.Append("<input type=""text""  class=""form-control"" id=""extField_" & indexNum & """  Columns=""18"" class=""form"" />" & vbCrLf)
            End If
          Case Else
            out.Append("<input type=""text"" class=""form-control"" id=""extField_" & indexNum & """ placeholder=""" & textLabel & """>")

        End Select
      Else
        'Defaults to outputting a text field if nothing is specified. 
        out.Append("<input type=""text"" class=""form-control"" id=""extField_" & indexNum & """ placeholder=""" & textLabel & """>")
      End If
      out.Append("</div>")
      out.Append("</div>")

      Return out.ToString()
    End Function
```

#### Unit tests

```
[TestMethod]
public void ResponsiveEPriceCustomFieldsOptionsTestMethod()
{

   //Initialize
    string inputStringOptions = "Test~Select: option1;option2;Option3;option4";
    
    
    //arrange
    UCSendePrice UCsendPriceInstance = new userControl_sendeprice_r1();

    string ExpectedHTMLResultOptions = @"<div class=""form-group""><label for=""extField_1"" class=""col-md-4 control-label"" id=""extLabelField_1"" >Test:</label>
<div class=""col-md-8""><select class=""form-control""  id=""extField_1""><option> option1</option><option>option2</option><option>Option3</option><option>option4</option></select></div></div>";
    

    //Act
    string actualHTMLCodeOptions = UCsendPriceInstance.BuildHtmlControlResponsive(inputStringOptions, 1);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(ExpectedHTMLResultOptions, actualHTMLCodeOptions);
}


[TestMethod]
public void ResponsiveEPriceCustomFieldsTextAreaTestMethod()
{

    //Initialize
    UCSendePrice uCsendPriceInstance = new userControl_sendeprice_r1();
    string inputStringTextArea = "Test~TextArea: option1;option2;Option3;option4";
    //arrange
    string ExpectedHTMLResultTextArea = @"<div class=""form-group""><label for=""extField_1"" class=""col-md-4 control-label"" id=""extLabelField_1"" >Test:</label>
<div class=""col-md-8""><textarea id=""extField_1"" class=""form-control"" type=""text"" rows=""3""  placeholder=""Test""> </textarea> </div></div>";


    //Act
    string actualHTMLCodeTextArea = uCsendPriceInstance.BuildHtmlControlResponsive(inputStringTextArea, 1);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(ExpectedHTMLResultTextArea, actualHTMLCodeTextArea);
}


[TestMethod]
public void ResponsiveEPriceCustomFieldsInputTextTestMethod()
{

    //Initialize
    UCSendePrice uCsendPriceInstance = new userControl_sendeprice_r1();
    string inputStringInputText = "Test Input~ option1;option2;Option3;option4";


    //arrange
    string ExpectedHTMLResultInputText = @"<div class=""form-group""><label for=""extField_1"" class=""col-md-4 control-label"" id=""extLabelField_1"" >Test Input:</label>
<div class=""col-md-8""><input type=""text"" class=""form-control"" id=""extField_1"" placeholder=""Test Input""></div></div>";


    //Act
    string actualHTMLCodeInputText = uCsendPriceInstance.BuildHtmlControlResponsive(inputStringInputText, 1);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(ExpectedHTMLResultInputText, actualHTMLCodeInputText);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Before we start, take a look at this comment of yours. It's a prime example of why you shouldn't *always* trust the comments.

> ```vb
> 'This gets the text that comes before the : 
> 'Example Company:TextArea would return TextArea. 
> controlOption = textSelection.Substring(0, textSelection.IndexOf(":"c))
> ```

The text *before* `:` is in fact `Company` ;)

---

Now, the name of the method `BuildHtmlControlResponsive`, IMHO "responsive" is referring the word "build. The builder is run in responsive mode and creates a `HtmlControl`.

> ```vb
> Public Function BuildHtmlControlResponsive(sourceText As String, indexNum As Integer) As String
> ```

In reality you're building a `ResponsiveHtmlControl`. So I suggest you rename the method. I also suggest you rename the parameters. (Please don't abbreviate field/method names)

```vb
Public Function BuildResponsiveHtmlControl(command As String, index As Integer) As String
```

## Syntax

You need to define the syntax. This is how I read the rules:

> { labelText~ [ inputType: [ selectOption [;....n] ] ] }

- { } (braces) Required syntax items. Do not type the braces.
- [ ] (brackets) Optional syntax items. Do not type the brackets.
- [;...n] Indicates the preceding item can be repeated n number of times. The occurrences are separated by semicolons.

The name of some of your variables makes no sense. I took the liberty to change all of them. You should also store the character position returned from `IndexOf` to avoid duplicate calls. And there's a bug in your code. What if there's only one option? Aka. no semicolon?

> ```vb
> Test~TextArea: option1
> ```

If we apply all the changes/fixes, the code will look like this:

```vb
Dim labelText As String = String.Empty
Dim inputType As String = String.Empty
Dim selectOptions As String() = Nothing
Dim position As Integer = command.IndexOf("~")

If (position > -1) Then

    Dim cursor As Integer = (position + 1)

    labelText = command.Substring(0, position)
    position = command.IndexOf(":", cursor)

    If (position > -1) Then

        inputType = command.Substring(cursor, (position - cursor)).ToLower()
        cursor = (position + 1)

        If ((inputType = "select") AndAlso (cursor < command.Length)) Then
            selectOptions = command.Substring(cursor).Split(";"c)
        End If

    End If

End If
```

## HTML

HTML code is usually written in lowercase, so I suggest you change it accordingly.

> ```vb
> controlOption.ToUpper()
> ```

The [input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html#input.text) element doesn't have an attribute named `Columns`. And you cannot have two [identical attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes) (you have two class attributes).

> ```vb
> out.Append("<input type=""text""  class=""form-control"" id=""extField_" & indexNum & """  Columns=""18"" class=""form"" />" & vbCrLf)
> ```

Why do you default to an input element if there are only one or less options? It makes no sense. I suggest you return an empty select element.

> ```vb
> Case "SELECT"
>     If (sourceText.IndexOf(";"c) <> -1) Then
>         ...
>     Else
>         ' text box. Syntax: name
>         out.Append("<input type=""text""  class=""form-control"" id=""extField_" & indexNum & """  Columns=""18"" class=""form"" />" & vbCrLf)
>     End If
> ```

It's pretty clear that you have a maintainability issue, but you also have a readability issue. If speed isn't that big of concern, then I have a great suggestion. VB.Net has a great support for writing XML in the code editor. But please note that XML is *not* HTML.

Again, if we apply all the changes/fixes, the code will look like this:

```vb
Dim elementId As String = String.Format("extField_{0}", index)
Dim labelId As String = String.Format("extLabelField_{0}", index)
Dim element As XElement = Nothing

Select Case inputType
    Case "textarea"
        element = <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id=<%= elementId %> placeholder=<%= labelText %>></textarea>
    Case "select"
        element = <select id=<%= elementId %>></select>
        Array.ForEach(If(selectOptions, {}), Sub(item) element.Add(<option><%= item %></option>))
    Case Else
        element = <input type="text" id=<%= elementId %> placeholder=<%= labelText %>/>
End Select

Dim root =
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4" for=<%= elementId %> id=<%= labelId %>>Test:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8"></div>
    </div>

root.Element("div").Add(element)

Return root.ToString()
```

The code looks even better when [viewed in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLiMt.jpg).

[image: Code]

## Unit test

I'm not sure why you use C# for unit testing, but if you can switch to VB.Net, here's how easy it is to write (and read) the expected result (assuming the index = 1234):

```vb
Dim command As String = "Test~select:option1;option2;option3;option4"

Dim expectedResult As String =
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="extField_1234" id="extLabelField_1234">Test:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <select id="extField_1234">
                <option>option1</option>
                <option>option2</option>
                <option>option3</option>
                <option>option4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>.ToString()
```

Print screen of Visual Studio code editor:

[image: Code]

## Source code

Here's the complete method body:

```vb
Public Function BuildResponsiveHtmlControl(command As String, index As Integer) As String

    Dim labelText As String = String.Empty
    Dim inputType As String = String.Empty
    Dim selectOptions As String() = {}
    Dim position As Integer = command.IndexOf("~")

    If (position > -1) Then

        Dim cursor As Integer = (position + 1)

        labelText = command.Substring(0, position)
        position = command.IndexOf(":", cursor)

        If (position > -1) Then

            inputType = command.Substring(cursor, (position - cursor)).ToLower()
            cursor = (position + 1)

            If ((inputType = "select") AndAlso (cursor < command.Length)) Then
                selectOptions = command.Substring(cursor).Split(";"c)
            End If

        End If

    End If

    Dim elementId As String = String.Format("extField_{0}", index)
    Dim labelId As String = String.Format("extLabelField_{0}", index)
    Dim element As XElement = Nothing

    Select Case inputType
        Case "textarea"
            element = <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id=<%= elementId %> placeholder=<%= labelText %>></textarea>
        Case "select"
            element = <select id=<%= elementId %>></select>
            Array.ForEach(If(selectOptions, {}), Sub(item) element.Add(<option><%= item %></option>))
        Case Else
            element = <input type="text" id=<%= elementId %> placeholder=<%= labelText %>/>
    End Select

    Dim root =
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4" for=<%= elementId %> id=<%= labelId %>>Test:</label>
            <div class="col-md-8"></div>
        </div>

    root.Element("div").Add(element)

    Return root.ToString()

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments and recommendations. I appreciate every word . I need to mention couple of things :
I am inheriting this VB code from a legacy system we are using right now and trying to replace with a C# system. though the naming convention is off , IT IS not how I declare my variables/methods (look at my C# unit testing code to have an idea.
Again my biggest concern and what i really want out of this question is how to maintain the tests? we change the css classes a lot which means i have to change the produced HTML which means changing my tests. is that ok

Comment: Ah, I see. You should add this to your question. And you should probably replace one of the tags with c#.